# nodejs server create file name 4000, when server started

Tags: node.js, express, nodemon

**When i started my nodejs express server on port 4000 using nodemon it create a new executable file 4000,**
And every time file changes and server started it throw error that address already in use and when i kill that process which are associated with these port then after it is throwing the same error

```
yarn dev
```

> it create 4000, file automatically at root level of project

again i change port to 5000

```
yarn dev
```

> again it create file 5000,

Comment: Share here full error log. Also, the line that starts your server is: `app.listen()` etc. ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After long struggle i have found the error . My .env file was like this:-

PORT=4000,
MONGODB_URI=mongodb://localhost:27017/test,

problem arises due added comma(,) after value . After removal of comma problem fixed

Comment: I had a similar issue where i used `;` to terminate a variable my mistake, try to remove all comas and semicolons.

Answer (score 1):

I Have faced same problem while I was using semicolon(;) after port number `PORT=5000;`. This problem arises because of semicolon. When I call the data using process.env.PORT then it gives me the port value like `5000;` (with semicolon).

Answer (score 0):

Like @pierpy said, does the line that starts your server say something like `app.listen(80)` (of course `80` is your port number).

If not, remove the line that 'starts' the server and replace it with `app.listen(PORT)` and change `PORT` to whatever port you want.

Comment: @SirStoplt  my server is running on heroku ,if i will put PORT directly then how it will take dynamic port from heroku $PORT variable.

Comment: No you don't understand, your supposed to change PORT to whatever numbers you want your port to be.

Comment: Please press the grey checkmark next to my answer so other people know that this helped you.